# Verifying the fundamental solution to the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, fundamental-solution

> $$\displaystyle u(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-(x-s)^2}{4t}}g(s)ds$$
> Verify the above function satisfies $u_t - u_{xx} = 0$ for any function $g$.

I wrote $$\displaystyle u_t = -\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{\pi} t^{\frac{3}{2}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-(x-s)^2}{4t}}g(s)ds + \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(x-s)^2}{4t^2} e^{\frac{-(x-s)^2}{4t}}g(s)ds$$ by the product rule.

and I got $$\displaystyle u_{xx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left (\frac{(x-s)^2}{4t^2}e^{\frac{-(x-s)^2}{4t}} - 2t e^{-\frac{(x-s)^2}{4t}} \right ) g(s)ds$$

However, I do not see how terms are supposed to cancel to get zero. Have I made a mistake?

Comment: Note that it suffices to check $\Phi (x, t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} e^{-|x-s|^2/4t}$ satisfies the heat equation (all the derivatives goes to this term)

Comment: Why does it suffice to check only that?

Comment: The $u_{xx}$ second term is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just made an algebra error.  You should have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ e^{-\frac{(x-s)^2}{4 t}}\right] = -\frac{(x-s) e^{-\frac{(x-s)^2}{4 t}}}{2 t} 
$$
and so
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \left[ e^{-\frac{(x-s)^2}{4 t}}\right] = \frac{(x-s)^2 e^{-\frac{(x-s)^2}{4 t}}}{4 t^2} - \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-s)^2}{4 t}}}{2 t} \neq \frac{(x-s)^2 e^{-\frac{(x-s)^2}{4 t}}}{4 t^2} - 2t e^{-\frac{(x-s)^2}{4 t}}.
$$
If you correct the second term in your expression for $u_{xx}$ and pull a factor of $t$ out of the denominator of the integral, you will see that it is equal to $u_t$.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by pull a factor of $t$ out? I can pull a $\frac{1}{t}$ out.

Comment: @hirotaFan:  Yes, that's what I meant.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
\varphi(s,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\exp\left(\frac{-s^{2}}{4t}\right).
$$
As you point out, the fundamental solution is
$$
u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(s)\varphi(x-s,t)ds=[g*\varphi(\cdot,t)](x).
$$
Therefore, $u_t(\cdot, t) = g * \varphi_t(\cdot, t)$ and $u_{xx}(\cdot, t) = g * \varphi_{xx}(\cdot, t)$.
It follows that one need only show $\varphi_t = \varphi_{xx}$.
This can be established by direct computation (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B1%2FSqrt%5B4*pi*t%5D+*+Exp%5B-s%5E2%2F%284*t%29%5D%2C+t%5D) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B1%2FSqrt%5B4*pi*t%5D+*+Exp%5B-s%5E2%2F%284*t%29%5D%2C+%7Bs%2C2%7D%5D)).

Comment: This is also a cool method! Did you kinda just...see that we can write this using convolution?

Comment: It's well known that (regular) solutions to the heat equation are obtained by convolving the fundamental solution $\varphi$ with the initial data $g$. This fact can be established using only tools from analysis of PDEs. Another way is to use probability (i.e., the [Feynman-Kac formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula)).